# Translate SQL to API request

Tags: sql, api

I got this simple table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Movies (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Title VARCHAR(255),
    Release_Date DATE,
    Rating INT
)
```

To get the list of the top 100 highest rated movies, the query would look like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Movies
ORDER BY Rating ASC
LIMIT 100
```

I don't know how rigorous the term is, but assuming the table is linked to an API, how would you 'translate' that query into a GET and/or POST request?

Could you also recommend me some documentation about complex API requests?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any MVC frameworks to build the API that returns Movie list.
Some of them are php / laravel, python / django and node / express.
All of these frameworks have "model" which handles database queries and "controller" which handles request and response for the API endpoints.

Comment: As it's currently written, your answer, though itself a clear description, probably does not answer the question directly enough for the OP to understand. Please explicate the connection more thoroughly.